# Anybody know what this piece is called?

Tags: part-identification

[image]

This came from a little car, and I'm trying to build that car using LDD, but I can't find the piece. Can someone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Bricklink this is called [Wedge 3 x 4 x 2/3 Cutout](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11291&idColor=5#T=C&C=5).

[image: yeah]

As Uli pointed out in the comments this part is called "**FRONT 4X3X2/3 W. BOW**" in LDD. The given image looks very similar. You can also see if this is really the part you're looking for by looking at [the 3D model of it](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=11291&tab=V).

---

<sub>**How I found it**: Searching by properties did not work (which usually does), and I knew that many Lego city police sets had red-colored vehicles, so on google I searched "lego city police" and hit images, and I saw an image of the front of the box for set 60243 which showed a truck that seemingly looked like it had this piece and I found the same set on bricklink. Then I looked at the part list, and it had this part!</sub>

Comment: LDD calls it **FRONT 4X3X2/3 W. BOW**